# create flex component with a map in React

Tags: reactjs, components, iteration, array.prototype.map

I have some data in an array of objects I want to put in different containers in pairs.

This is the structure of the dummy data array:

```js
const projects = [
  {
    title,
    text,
    ...
  },
  {
    title,
    text,
    ...
  },
  {
    title,
    text,
    ...
  },
  {
    title,
    text,
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

This is my component:

```js
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <HomePage className="pageContainer">
      <div className="projects" style={display: 'flex'}>
        {projects.map( (project, index) => {
            return <Project key={index} project={project} />
        })}
      </div>
    </HomePage>
  )
}
```

Now this works perfectly fine, but it gives me the following html:

```html
<div class="projects">
  <div class="projectCard">
    <!-- content of project[0] -->
  </div>
  <div class="projectCard">
    <!-- content of project[1] -->
  </div>
  <div class="projectCard">
    <!-- content of project[2] -->
  </div>
  <div class="projectCard">
    <!-- content of project[3] -->
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Ideally, I'd like the following:

```html
<div class="projects">
  <div class="projectRow">
    <div class="projectCard">
      <!-- content of project[0] -->
    </div>
    <div class="projectCard">
      <!-- content of project[1] -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="projectRow">
    <div class="projectCard">
      <!-- content of project[2] -->
    </div>
    <div class="projectCard">
      <!-- content of project[3] -->
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

I could probably do a hacky way, just as below, but there must be a better way (this works fine as I only have four projects currently)??

```js
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <HomePage className="pageContainer">
      <div className="projects">
        <div className="projectRow">
          {projects.map( (project, index) => {
            if (index % 2 === 1) {
              return <Project key={index} project={project} />
            }
          })}
        </div>
        <div className="projectRow">
          {projects.map( (project, index) => {
            if (index % 2 !== 1) {
              return <Project key={index} project={project} />
            }
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </HomePage>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const Home = () => {
    const projects: unknown[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

    const groupLength = 2;

    if (projects.length % groupLength !== 0) {
        // means projects can not be divided into groups  
        // of "groupLength" without leftovers
        return null;
    }

    const groupsNumber = projects.length / groupLength;

    return (
        <HomePage className="pageContainer">
            <div className="projects">
                {[...Array(groupsNumber).keys()].map((_, groupIndex) => (
                    <div className="projectRow">
                        {projects
                            .slice(groupIndex * groupLength, (groupIndex + 1) * groupLength)
                            .map((project, index) => (
                                <Project key={groupIndex * groupLength + index} project={project} />
                            ))}
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </HomePage>
    );
};
```

Comment: This works a treat, thanks. Do you mind adding a little bit of details about what going on, especially with this `[...Array(groupsNumber).keys()].map((_, groupIndex) => (`

Comment: [...Array(groupsNumber).keys()] creates an array of 0, 1, 2, ..., groupsNumber, and later it is mapped to divide projects into groupsNumber groups using slice